# Youtube API: is there a way to get a list of my YouTube homepage feed videos?

Tags: youtube-api

Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with the YouTube API.

I could confidently tell that anyone of us who has been using YouTube on their phones experienced being fed with a list of videos right after opening the app.
I think that this homepage feed is being computed over a set of parameters such as my subscriptions, my activities, trending videos and so on (as a side note, this feed gets recomputed after every refresh).

I was wondering if there's any way to get a list of these videos' IDs, just by providing a user ID as an input (e.g. the one linked to my Google account) at a API level.

Desiderata:

- Input: MY_YOUTUBE_USERID
- Output: [1ST_FEEDVIDEO_ID, 2ND_FEEDVIDEO_ID, ..., NTH_FEEDVIDEO_ID]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think they don't have public API for that, you may want to check the available API they share with developers here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/

Comment: you can check this one too https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets